# Combox selecteditem adding extra letter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C# and trying to understand how things work. So I created a two forms. First one has a textbox and the second one has a combobox with a button that sends offer help to that computer.  From the text box I add computer names. once I click the OK button it loads all my computer names to the combobox.

```
string[] computerlist = txtComputers.Text.Split(new[]{'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
frmHome _frmhome = new frmHome();
_frmhome.cbComputerList.Items.AddRange(computerlist);
_frmhome.ShowDialog();
_frmhome.Dispose();
```

When I select a computer from the dropbox and click Offer_help button, offer remote window comes up saying its trying to connect to the user but then fails.

```
private void Offerhelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    CompName = cbComputerList.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var _offerhelp = new ProcessStartInfo();
    _offerhelp.FileName = "msra.exe";
    _offerhelp.Arguments = String.Format("/offerRA" + " " + CompName);
    Process.Start(_offerhelp);
  }
```

I tried running in debug mode and I see that "CompName" variable is

```
"/offerRA Lab1\r"
```

if I remove the "\r" it actually works.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Also, Is there a way I can create a new class for the selected item and make it a global variable so I can use it say if I create 4-5 forms and use that computer name in all forms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you work backwards and check what computerlist[0] contains. Does it still contain the \r?

Comment: It's not combobox issue. Check your `computerList` variable. Probably you need to use `Split` with `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
string[] computerlist = txtComputers.Text.Split(new[]{'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Is the issue. `\n` is the newline operator, and `\r` is carriage return. Depending on OS / Program, you can use `\r\n` to determine a 'NewLine'.

Use

```
string[] computerlist = txtComputers.Text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the proper character.

EDIT: In terms of your comment, add a static property to your form:

```
class MyForm
{
    public static string SelectedComputer { get; set;}
}
```

you can then reference this anywhere by

```
MyForm.SelectedComputer
```

Set this variable on your `cbComputerList.SelectedIndexChanged` event. Just check to make sure the value is greater than 0 then set it.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfect. Is there a way to make the selected computer a global variable so I can use it in every form?

Comment: You could make it a static field on some form and reference it, but why not have a regular property on your main form, then pass a reference to your main form to each other form. Usually you try to stay away from static properties, but if that's what you want then it should be fine. (Or even better, a model that is a reference on your main form, then just pass the model instead of the whole form)

Comment: posted a sample with static. I would have to see your structure if I were to help with the other two methods.